# Minecraft world not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in one of the snapshots for 1.9 in my survival world i think it was 15w49b and all the sudden my game crashed so i load back my launcher and the worlds not there but when i went to my saves folder its still there and im not sure why it wouldn't be showing i have a backup but it's from like 2 months before it crashed so it's not going to do me any good. Here is a picture of what the inside of my world folder looks like https://gyazo.com/8ee7892269f4d6c2c04a61020e6a631a please help!

Comment: Could you upload the world file?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Go to drive.google.com, drag your world folder into Google drive, right click the uploaded folder, click "Share", click "Get Shareable link" in the window that pops up, then copy and paste the link you get to here.

Comment: im doing it right now it's just taking it's time and it's a 280mb world

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz_jSINfo-FNWU9jaEtweG9QMms&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `level.dat` file has disappeared, which contains information about the world (name, seed, generator options) and the player (inventory contents, location).

I created a new `level.dat` file that you should be able to paste into the world's folder to have it show up again:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dLLm3BlRZoN0phSkdndnVmYjQ/view?usp=sharing

Your world still contained `level.dat_mcr`, which is the `level.dat` from worlds before the Anvil format. This meant I could copy over the world's seed, which should hopefully prevent terrain generation issues.

I've put the data from your player's file that was in the `playerdata` folder (normally only read from in multiplayer/LAN, but written to in singleplayer) into `level.dat`, so you should keep your inventory as well.

I did this in 1.9pre2, so I'm not sure if you'll need to upgrade. (It's probably best not to be playing on outdated snapshots with known major bugs without frequent backups anyway)

Comment: I just started playing on 1.9pre2 so thats works fine

Comment: unfortunately i will not be able to test it now i have to head in to town but i will test it when i get back and tell you what happend

Comment: Well im not sure i put the new level.dat folder into my world folder and it's still not there is there anything else i need to do? LIke change the folder type because right now its an internet explorer type folder

Comment: If you need me to upload my new world folder i can

Comment: @user139673 Did you put `level.dat` in the right place (so it's along with `icon.png`) and in the right folder (the one in your saves, not a downloaded one)? It don't think it should be an Internet Explorer type folder, don't know what that means.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/53c9b9ffb880af46ccc1db4a4a59f19e

Comment: Could my world be corrupted

Comment: @user139673 All of your world is still there; I was able to play on it fine with the level.dat I made (you were in the nether at a zombie pig farm or something?). Try downloading the `level.dat` I linked again; it should only be 2kB, not 34kB.

Comment: When i go to save it it gives me on option to save it as a html web page html only file or a webpage complete file. when i save it as a html it's a 8kb and the complete is 34kb

Comment: You need to download the file, not the webpage that the file is downloaded from. Click the download button near the top: http://i.imgur.com/aC4cPqp.png

Comment: Alright it worked thank you so much man i would of never of know that's what the problem was. everything seemed to work fine and was still there a little low on the frame rate but probably because of all the entitys. Anyway thanks for the help!